# WordPress - why my custom posts are not accessible with SEO paths

Tags: wordpress, post, path, seo, custom-post-type

So, I've created custom post types (from code), and when I access post in this format:

```
/?post-type=post-slug
```

then it works, but when I'm trying to access the post in this format:

```
/post-type/post-slug
```

then it doesn't.

Instead of post home page is displayed.
Why is that?

When I edit such a post "view post post-type" link is leading to post in second format, when I print out post path from template second format is used, when comment is submitted user is redirected to page in second format. Basically everywhere is used that second format, but it's just not working?!

BTW, when I started making my website Apache's rewrite engine was not turned on, but now it is. Not sure can that have some influence on this? Maybe it's remembered somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, found it!

I had a `flush_rewrite_rules()` function call in my functions.php and it was causing that behavior.

At some point, probably after I added new content type and before visiting permalinks page I was unable to see post, so, at some forum I've found that this function should be called after the code that creates content type. That didn't help, but I left it there and forgot about it.

Mark, thank you for your hints anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `settings > permalinks` and then select the Post Name option.

Click Save Changes then refresh the post type.

Saving the permalinks settings updates the `.htaccess` file which quite often fixes these issues.

Comment: I'm already using Post name option, but it only works with original Post content type, not with the one's I've created.
How do you mean "refresh post type"? What that means?

Comment: By refresh I meant view the page/pages where the custom post types appear after refreshing the permalinks.

Comment: Also did you define a slug when creating the custom post type? 
`'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'post-slug' ),`

Comment: Yes, I did, but didn't help. :(

Comment: How are you displaying the custom posts on the website? Do you have the templates set up? Would be easier to help if you have a test site.